# jquery show and hide with paging

Tags: php, jquery

I have page display photos and videos with paging (5 items in every page) i create two buttons (photos and videos) to show every one separately by using show and hide jquery functions but the problem is when i choose videos its ok and display videos but when i choose next page it direct and show the next photos not videos:

```
<div id="photo">
    {if $mediaRows}
    {include file="paging.tpl" paging=$mediaPaging}
       <div id="mediaListContainer">
         {foreach $mediaArray as $media}
        {include file='contributor.media.container.tpl'}
   {/foreach}
       </div>
        {include file="paging.tpl" paging=$mediaPaging}
    {else}
         <p class="notice">{$lang.noMediaAlbum}</p>
    {/if}
</div>
     <div id="video" hidden>
       {if $mediaRowsV}
         {include file="paging.tpl" paging=$mediaPagingV}
          <div id="mediaListContainer">
         {foreach $mediaArrayV as $media}
        {include file='contributor.media.container.tpl'}
       {/foreach}
      </div>
       {include file="paging.tpl" paging=$mediaPaging}
      {else}
        <p class="notice">{$lang.noMediaAlbum}</p>
        {/if}
</div>
```

I know that is happened because i put div videos hidden but i do this because i need my default value (when user is getting page) is photos.
How i can solve this problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be what you are looking for, it works with BootStrap (so you may need the include the files and was written for bs 1.11.4), but here is the class I write for pagination:

```
<?php
class Paginator {
    /**
     * @var mysqli
     */
    private $_conn;
    private $_limit;
    private $_page;
    private $_query;
    private $_total;

    public function __construct( $conn, $query ) {

        $this->_conn = $conn;
        $this->_query = $query;

        $rs= $this->_conn->query( $this->_query );
        $this->_total = $rs->num_rows;

    }

    public function get_data( $limit = 10, $page = 1 ) {

        $this->_limit = $limit;
        $this->_page = $page;

        if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
            $query = $this->_query;
        } else {
            $query = $this->_query . " LIMIT " . ( ( $this->_page - 1 ) * $this->_limit ) . ", " . $this->_limit . ";";
        }

        $rs = $this->_conn->query( $query );

        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs) ) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }

        $result = new stdClass();
        $result->page = $this->_page;
        $result->limit = $this->_limit;
        $result->total = $this->_total;
        $result->data = $results;

        return $result;
    }

    public function create_links( $links, $list_class ) {
        if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
            return '';
        }

        $last = ceil( $this->_total / $this->_limit );

        $start = ( ( $this->_page - $links ) > 0 ) ? $this->_page - $links : 1;
        $end = ( ( $this->_page + $links ) < $last ) ? $this->_page + $links : $last;

        $html = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';

        $class = ( $this->_page == 1 ) ? "disabled" : "";
        if ($this->_page > 1) {
            $html .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?page=pagelimit=' . $this->_limit . '&_page=' . ( $this->_page - 1 ) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';
        }

        if ( $start > 1 ) {
            $html .= '<li><a href="?page=page&limit=' . $this->_limit . '&_page=1">1</a></li>';
            $html .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
        }

        for ( $i = $start ; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
            $class = ( $this->_page == $i ) ? "active" : "";
            $html .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?pagepage&limit=' . $this->_limit . '&_page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
        }

        if ( $end < $last ) {
            $html .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
            $html .= '<li><a href="?page=pagelimit=' . $this->_limit . '&_page=' . $last . '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
        }

        $class = ( $this->_page == $last ) ? "disabled" : "";
        if ($this->_limit < $this->_total) {
            $html .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?page=page&limit=' . $this->_limit . '&_page=' . ( $this->_page + 1 ) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';
        }

        $html .= '</ul>';

        return $html;
    }
}
?>
```

In the `create_links` functions, you replace the ?page=page with whatever you need, it worked perfect for me and hope it does for you too!

Comment: thx but i need to solve this problem without changing paging class